# The Fenics shows "AttributeError: type object 'dolfin.cpp.MPI' has no attribute 'process_number' "

Tags: python, fenics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Olohs.png)
when we use the fenics, that shows "AttributeError: type object 'dolfin.cpp.MPI' has no attribute 'process_number' ".

How we solve it? And I intend to carry out the code. Here, the code is Link to file :https://fenicsproject.org/olddocs/dolfin//1.3.0/python/demo/documented/cahn-hilliard/python/documentation.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.